# Average for every n row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with about 1000 rows and I want to find the average for every 16 rows and add it in the next column without empty cells between them. I found this formula, which works perfect if my data starts from the first row.

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)*16-15),0,0,16,1))
```

I am trying to make it work for data that starts from the second row, since the first row has the headers. I tried a lot of things without success. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A1)*16-14),0,0,16,1))
```

should be placed in **B1**

If copied down:

**B1** will show the average of **A2** thru **A17**
**B2** will show the average of **A18** thru **A33**

etc.

**EDIT#2:**

To get **B2** to represent the average of **A2** thru **A17,** use:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A2)*16-30),0,0,16,1))
```

Comment: This one skipped the first row and start printing for the second 16 group

Comment: Will produce the average of rows **2** thru **17** and if copied down will produce the average of **18** thru **33**

Comment: Nope. Start from 18

Comment: To start from **18** put the *formula* in the **second row!**

Comment: The problem is that I want to put it on B2 since it has also a header. Then show average from A2 thru A17, A18 thru A33 etc

Comment: Then see my **EDIT#2!**

Answer (score 2):

A formula that will work regardless of where the data is located is the following:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$2,16*(ROW()-ROW($C$2)),0,16,1))
```

where $B$2 and $C$2 are adjusted to the top cell of the data column and the averaging column, respectively. E.g.,

[image]

Column **B** is just a counting sequence. All of the cells with values in column **C** contain the formula in cell **D2**.